Spring Data Scrolling (Window<>) with specification filtering
Spring Data 3.1 introduced the Scrollable API, which allows us to Iterate over data. The documentation describes this only for defined methods within the repository. Example from the Documentation
Window<User> findFirst10ByLastnameOrderByFirstname(String lastname, OffsetScrollPosition position);

In order to be more flexible and support more filter, I would like to query by Specification.
Something like
Window<User> findAll(Specification<User> specification, ScrollPosition position, Limit limit, Sort sort );

But this won't even start.
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in io.d4e.graphql.domain.repository.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Could not create query for public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Window io.d4e.graphql.domain.repository.UserRepository.findAll(org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification,org.springframework.data.domain.ScrollPosition,org.springframework.data.domain.Limit,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Window io.d4e.graphql.domain.repository.UserRepository.findAll(org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification,org.springframework.data.domain.ScrollPosition,org.springframework.data.domain.Limit,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort); No property 'findAll' found for type 'User'
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:907) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:785) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
   ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Window io.d4e.graphql.domain.repository.UserRepository.findAll(org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification,org.springframework.data.domain.ScrollPosition,org.springframework.data.domain.Limit,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Window io.d4e.graphql.domain.repository.UserRepository.findAll(org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification,org.springframework.data.domain.ScrollPosition,org.springframework.data.domain.Limit,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort); No property 'findAll' found for type 'User'
   at org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException.create(QueryCreationException.java:101) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
   at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
   at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
   at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:88) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
   at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260) ~[na:na]
   at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:88) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
   at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:357) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
   at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:279) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
   at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:135) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
   at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:113) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
   at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
   at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:132) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1833) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
   ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Window io.d4e.graphql.domain.repository.UserRepository.findAll(org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification,org.springframework.data.domain.ScrollPosition,org.springframework.data.domain.Limit,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort); No property 'findAll' found for type 'UserEntity'
   at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:106) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
   at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:124) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
   at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:258) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
   at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:95) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
   at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:111) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
   ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property 'findAll' found for type 'UserEntity'
   at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:90) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
   at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:443) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
   at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:419) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
   at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:372) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:330) ~[na:na]
   at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:354) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
   at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:332) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
   at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
   at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:259) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
   at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
   at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179) ~[na:na]
   at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992) ~[na:na]
   at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
   at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
   at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921) ~[na:na]
   at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
   at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[na:na]
   at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:260) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
   at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:389) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
   at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
   at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179) ~[na:na]
   at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992) ~[na:na]
   at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
   at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
   at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921) ~[na:na]
   at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
   at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[na:na]
   at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:390) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
   at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:100) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
   at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:100) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
   ... 46 common frames omitted

Any suggestions as to how I can make this happen?

Specifications can only be evaluated from JpaSpecificationExecutor, query derivation doesn't support specification objects.
You call would look like:
UserRepository extends Repository<User, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<User> { … }

// spec is a Specification<User> object
// scroll accepts your final `ScrollPosition`
repo.findBy(spec, query -> query.limit(…).sortBy(…).scroll(…));

